# Errors when trying to start mongo db server from Java program

Tags: java, mongodb, cmd

I tried to start mongo db server from java program. I am trying execute the mongo db start command from Java. And it's not working.

```
public static void accessCommandLine(){
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\" && mongod.exe --dbpath \"D:\\Mongo\\data \" "});

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output is empty.

When I am trying to execute the command from cmd, it's working. 
Can someone help me on this

Comment: What is the error/non-required behavior?

Comment: Program is being terminated without any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
Process p = rt.exec("C://Program%20Files//MongoDB%202.6%20Standard//mongod.exe --dbpath D://Mongo//data");
```